# Knex Heroku Error: self signed certificate

Tags: javascript, ssl, heroku, knex.js, dotenv

I keep getting this error:

`Error: self signed certificate`

When running this command in the terminal:

```
knex migrate:latest --env production
```

My knexfile.js

```
       require('dotenv').config(); 
module.exports = {
      development: {
        client: "pg",
        connection: {
          host: "localhost",
          database: "my-movies"
        }
      },

      production: {
        client: "pg",
        connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL
      }
    };
```

My .env file:

```
DATABASE_URL=<my_database_url>?ssl=true
```

Heroku app info:

```
Addons:         heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
Auto Cert Mgmt: false
Dynos:
Git URL:        https://git.heroku.com/path-name.git
Owner:          xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.com
Region:         us
Repo Size:      0 B
Slug Size:      0 B
Stack:          heroku-18
Web URL:        https://my-appname.herokuapp.com/
```

I've tried putting a key value pair in the production in the knexfile of ssl: true and I get the same error. I've done it this way in the past many, many times and have never had this issue. Wondering if Heroku has changed anything but while searching their docs I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You could try to downgrade your pg version to 7.4.3

Comment: @dfrancese Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 26):

The following config at `knexfile.js` worked for me.

```js
...
production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: { 
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
    }
}
...
```

where the `DATABASE_URL` is what you get by running `heroku config --yourAppName`

Comment: You just got me out of a hellhole

Comment: thank you, it was quite hard to find documentation about the ssl option on knex docs. your answer solved the issue for me

Comment: Where is the documentation about this option?

Comment: DUDE! You've just made the world a better place to be in.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a breaking change in pg@^8 (2020/02/25) cf. [this heroku help forum](https://help.heroku.com/MDM23G46/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-i-upgrade-to-pg-8).

You can get the [full pg@^8 announcement](https://node-postgres.com/announcements#2020-02-25) but here is the relevant passage:

> Now we will use the default ssl options to tls.connect which includes rejectUnauthorized being enabled. This means your connection attempt may fail if you are using a self-signed cert.

And it seems heroku is using self-signed certificates somewhere.

possible solutions:

- downgrade to pg@^7
- instruct pg@^8 to ignore problematic certificates `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }` (see announcement linked above)
- find a way to download and trust the certificate [instructions](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/1054)

Comment: adding `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }` did not work, I still get the same error :(

Comment: @j86 I am also stuck having tried the above SSL config . Were you able to proceed ahead ?  If you can please confirm, that would be very nice of you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }` pg config isn't working for me at the moment either.. but I found a temporary (maybe permanent) solution via the [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js)

Set the following config var:

`heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a config like:

```js
...
production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: { 
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
    }
}
...
```

...and it still isn't working for you, make sure you don't have a `?ssl=true` or `sslmode` set in DB your connection string.

If `ssl` is set in your connection string it will override the `ssl` part of your config, meaning behavior is equivalent to:

```js
...
production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: { 
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: true
    }
}
...
```

Removing the `ssl` entry from your connection string will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was not using just a connection string but also adding the CA from my database as an option to the connection object in knex.

```
production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: { 
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: { 
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
          ca: process.env.POSTGRES_CA,
        }
    }
}
```