# Failing to run migration Postgres on Heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, typeorm

Well, when I enter heroku bash and try to run `npx typeorm migration:run` it just throws me an error:
[image]

What's weird is that locally it works when the DATABASE is on localhost like this in .env file:
`DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:docker@localhost:5432/gittin`

This is my `ormconfig.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    "type": "postgres",
    "url": process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    "entities": ["dist/entities/*.js"],
    "cli": {
        "migrationsDir": "src/database/migrations",
        "entitiesDir": "src/entities"
    }
}
```

Yes, I added the heroku postgres addon to the app.

PS: If needed, this is the repo of the project: https://github.com/joaocasarin/gittin

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)?

Comment: I've also found [this](https://help.heroku.com/DR0TTWWD/seeing-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-errors-in-postgres).
I think you have to edit ```ormconfig.js``` and add: ```ssl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'```. This enables *ssl* only if *Node.js* environment is **production** allowing for a secure connection in *Heorku* and also a "non secure" connection for local developement.

Comment: Hi @CarloCorradini , I can't see how the first link can help me, because I'm not finding the conf file, and still, the connection would still request the SSL activated... Regarding your second comment, I tried your way, but as I was researching, the `ssl` field in the ormconfig.js should not be a boolean value, it should be an object like this: https://gist.github.com/joaocasarin/85c29ca545ddc77cafcd8a5aa41af49a

Comment: It works, I've used ```ssl``` in many projects :).
For an example take a look [here](https://github.com/GiovanniZotta/fog_cloud_project/blob/main/graphmarket/services/service-products/bootstrap.ts#L18). PS: Have you tried?

Comment: @CarloCorradini yes I did try, here is the new error: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/48847394/125986054-ac5f51fc-2d23-474c-ba3e-73bbdbe7a197.png

Comment: and the `ormconfig.js`: https://github.com/joaocasarin/gittin/blob/main/ormconfig.js

Comment: UPDATE: using `"ssl": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : false` instead worked.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was discussing with Carlo in the comments, I had to add the `ssl` property in the `ormconfig.js`, but not only setting it to true when the environment was `production`. So according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61125814/14318729), I had to put `{ rejectUnauthorized: false }` when production mode, and just false when not.

So the `ormconfig.js` is like this right now:

```js
module.exports = {
    "type": "postgres",
    "ssl": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : false,
    "url": process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    "entities": ["dist/entities/*.js"],
    "cli": {
        "migrationsDir": "src/database/migrations",
        "entitiesDir": "src/entities"
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is the solution, marks it as the correct answer :)

Comment: @CarloCorradini I was waiting 2 days to be able to select it as correct, thanks for remembering me!